# Making an object from multiple properties

Tags: javascript

I have an **array** of objects like below :

```
var ara = [
 {
    Name: 'Lionel',
    Age: 32,
    Positions: ['Winger', 'Midfield', 'Striker']
 },
 {
    Name: 'Neymar',
    Age: 28,
    Position: ['Winger', 'Striker']
 }
]
```

I want this :

```
var profiles = [
    {
        Identity: {Name: 'Lionel', Age: 32},
        Positions: ['Winger', 'Midfield', 'Striker'],
    },
    {        
        Identity: {Name: 'Neymar', Age: 28},
        Positions: ['Winger', 'Striker']
];
```

Comment: `var profiles = ara.map(({Name,Age,Positions}) => {
 return {Identity:{Name,Age},Positions}
})`

Comment: Please show us what you tried and tell us where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use an `.map()` function and reformat your array

```js
var ara = [
 {
    Name: 'Lionel',
    Age: 32,
    Positions: ['Winger', 'Midfield', 'Striker']
 },
 {
    Name: 'Neymar',
    Age: 28,
    Positions: ['Winger', 'Striker']
 }
]


var profiles = ara.map((obj) => {
  return {
    Identity:{
      Name: obj.Name,
      Age: obj.Age
    },
    Positions: obj.Positions
  }
})

console.log(profiles)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) with [rest in object destructuring `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Rest_in_Object_Destructuring) and build a new object with [short hand properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer).

```js
const
    ara = [{ Name: 'Lionel', Age: 32, Positions: ['Winger', 'Midfield', 'Striker'] }, { Name: 'Neymar', Age: 28, Position: ['Winger', 'Striker'] }],
    profiles = ara.map(({ Positions, ...Identity }) =>
        ({ Identity, Positions })
    );

console.log(profiles);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```